# Using Google Prettify to display HTML

Tags: javascript, prettify

for Google Prettify to display HTML code sample properly, you should replace all the `<` with `&lt;` and all the `>` with `&gt;`.

How do you automate that process using JavaScript only ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you put your code inside an [`<xmp>`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.5.2.1) element, you don't need to escape HTML special characters as shown in the [tests](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#632)

> ```
>  <h1>HTML using XMP</h1>
>  <xmp class="prettyprint" id="htmlXmp"
>  ><html>
>    <head>
>      <title>Fibonacci number</title>
>    </head>
>    <body>
>      <noscript>
>        <dl>
>          <dt>Fibonacci numbers</dt>
>          <dd>1</dd>
>          <dd>1</dd>
>          <dd>2</dd>
>          <dd>3</dd>
>          <dd>5</dd>
>          <dd>8</dd>
>          &hellip;
>        </dl>
>      </noscript>
>
>      <script type="text/javascript"><!--
>  function fib(n) {
>    var a = 1, b = 1;
>    var tmp;
>    while (--n >= 0) {
>      tmp = a;
>      a += b;
>      b = tmp;
>    }
>    return a;
>  }
>
>  document.writeln(fib(10));
>  // -->
>      </script>
>    </body>
>  </html>
>  </xmp>
> ```

Comment: @Brett, it'll work as long as the HTML you're prettifying doesn't contain the string `"</xmp"`.

Comment: I even didn't know such the tag exists oO

Comment: problem: xmp is obsolete, and vertical extra space appears.

Comment: Had some issues with bootstrap styling overwriting prettify. Solved by surrounding with 
<pre><xmp class="prettyprint lang-html">
...
</xmp></pre>

Comment: `<xmp>` HTML tag is now obselete.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a global replace to the content using a RegEx.

```
var regex = new RegExp("<", "g");
console.log(content.replace(regex, "&lt;"));
```

Comment: You need to properly escape ampersands as well.